# error calling jsonp cross-domain webservice

Tags: jquery, cordova, jsonp

I'm a .NET developer trying to create a simple cross-platform (Android/iOS) app using PhoneGAP. I have problem in using my .NET web services in PhoneGAP app, it is my JS code:

```
    function DoIt()
{
    var surl = "http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: surl,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        data: { "UserID": "1234" },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(val) {
            var myjsonobject = val;
            alert(myjsonobject.accounting[0].firstname + ' ' + myjsonobject.accounting[0].lastname);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(error); },
        async: false,
        cache: false
    });

}
DoIt();
```

and it is my server side page (CS):

```
        public string output = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params["callback"] != null)
        {
            output = Request.Params["callback"] + "(" + GetData() + ");";
        }
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        string r = @"
            { ""accounting"" : [   // accounting is an array in employees.
                                { ""firstName"" : ""John"",  // First element
                                  ""lastName""  : ""Doe"",
                                  ""age""       : 23 },

                                { ""firstName"" : ""Mary"",  // Second Element
                                  ""lastName""  : ""Smith"",
                                  ""age""       : 32 }
                              ], // End ""accounting"" array.                                 
              ""sales""       : [ // Sales is another array in employees.
                                { ""firstName"" : ""Sally"", // First Element
                                  ""lastName""  : ""Green"",
                                  ""age""       : 27 },

                                { ""firstName"" : ""Jim"",   // Second Element
                                  ""lastName""  : ""Galley"",
                                  ""age""       : 41 }
                              ] // End ""sales"" Array.
            }";

        return r;
    }
```

(ASPX):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Rest.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnlineG.Rest" %>
<%=output %>   
..... HTML page
```

```
</div>
</form>
```

I get following error:

```
Error: jQuery182046418637151657827_1408038693745 was not called
```

The number in front of JQuery changes each time, I've seen some instances of this problem in google but none of the post could solve my problem, what is going wrong? should I check/change anything on my server or some code is missing?

Comment: jQuery "cheats" and sets the name of the callback function to something random, then inserts the script tag, as JSONP isn't really ajax, jQuery just makes it look that way to make things easier. It looks like the server doesn't respond with JSONP and doesn't set the name of the wrapping callback function accordingly, and that's probably because you left that param out, try doing `"http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx?callback=?"` and make sure you set the name of the callback function to what jQuery passes etc.

Comment: I changed surl to=var surl = "http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx?callback=?"; but again got the same error, can you please explain more

Comment: what do you mean exactly by: and make sure you set the name of the callback function to what jQuery passes etc.? JQuery makes a random name, so how can I know what is being passed? passing: http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx?callback=1234, gives me the correct result on browser, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I has the similar problems before (the server side I used node.js), don't remember how I exactly fix it. I don't have environment to test your case. But here are some hints for you to fix them,

1. You need pass the call back function name in the url, so it should be, 
   var surl = "http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx?callback=success",
2. Write a separate js function in your page to do the json data process, like,

   ```
    
   function success(data) {
   //your code
   var myjsonobject = data;
   alert(myjsonobject.accounting[0].firstname + ' ' + myjsonobject.accounting[0].lastname);
   }
   function DoIt()
   {
   var surl = "http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx";
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: surl,
       crossDomain: true,
       contentType: "application/javascript",
       data: { "UserID": "1234" },
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function(val) {
           success(val);
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert(error); },
       async: false,
       cache: false
   });

   }
   DoIt();
   ```
3. Make sure the server side will finally return "success(your json data);", if the following code not work, you have to use separate web api/service to do it;

   ```
    
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Request.Params["callback"] != null)
       {
           //here will return "success(...)"
           output = Request.Params["callback"] + "(" + GetData() + ");";
       }
   }
   ```
4. Probably you need specify the output content type in server side, like,
   ...Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";

Let me know if it works:)

Comment: can you please give me some code hints? all my codes are above, where should I add Response.ContentType? You mean I should use Response.Write instead of displaying output in HTML?

Comment: Did you try the first 3 steps? The 4th step is not suitable for your case, cause you are also showing other html content. "<%=output %>   
..... HTML page"

The "http://www.silverlight4web.com/onlinegame/rest.aspx" is supposed to do by web api/web service and only feed to ajax call.

Comment: can you please declare the steps 2 & 3 in more detail? can you give me code samples?